# Is it possible to maintain two different font size in Chart.JS based on screen size?

Tags: javascript, css, chart.js

In one of my projects, I use Chart.JS for some graph-related work. Where I use different font sizes for legend, ticks, scaleLabel, and tooltips. Everything is working fine on the large devices, but the problem arises when I test the graph on the mobile device. Where font size becomes too large. So my plan is to use two different font sizes to overcome the issue.

But, I didn't find out any option in chart.js to use multiple font sizes or no option to use any other unit except px.

Can anyone help me with how can I adjust the font size on different devices for chart.js?

Comment: check this https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/responsive.html

Answer (score 0):

Fonts documentation: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/fonts.html

You have a property to set the size of the font. You can choose to put it in the defaults before creating the chart. In this case you can just put a switch on it otherwise if you are going to set it in the config for each part you can set a fontsize you can do it with a ternary operator